# django - Unsupported lookup for JSONField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-jsonfield

I am having a Json field in my models as -

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    detailed_stock           = JSONField(load_kwargs={'object_pairs_hook': collections.OrderedDict},default=dict)
```

I am having values in my database like  -

```
{
  "total":0,
  "5[1]":0
}
```

I am trying to filter objects with total = 0, for that I tried -

`Product.objects.filter(detailed_stock__total = 0)`
but it throws error -

`Unsupported lookup 'total' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.`

as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) the following code is permitted.

this is full traceback-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_access.py", line 102, in dispatch
    request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\bekaim\accounts\views.py", line 142, in get_queryset
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(detailed_stock__total = 0)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 836, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 854, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1253, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1271, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1277, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1215, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1069, in build_lookup
    lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1115, in try_transform
    (name, lhs.output_field.__class__.__name__))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'total' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
[31/Dec/2018 16:13:37] "GET /accounts/product-list/?clean=outofstock HTTP/1.1" 500 150927
```

I searched on internet but unable to find the solution, please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are using [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield) as indicated by `load_kwargs={'object_pairs_hook': collections.OrderedDict}` instead of [django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField).

`django-jsonfield` is for databases which don't offer a native `dict` type and is based on a simple [`TextField`](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/blob/19b62ed3c02674b2ee3d61353312ffa75be373c4/jsonfield/fields.py#L154). When you access the field value using `product.detail_stock` the internally saved `str` is converted to `dict` using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) by the field itself. Hence you can only use operations like `icontains` and `contains` for querying that field.

If you are using postgres as a database, you are able to take full advantage of `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` as the documentation states. But you have to import the correct `JSONfield` by using `django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`.

There is a solution for [mysql](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html) (package [django-mysql](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql)) too.

Comment: ok, there is problem, so if now I change the field will it migrate without any problem ?

Comment: I doubt that since both fields have a different internal structure. But you could give it a try and report if it works.

Comment: Otherwise you have to migrate your data by 1. add a new JSONField (postgres) with a different name, 2. Use a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to copy the data to the new field, 3. remove the original field, 4. rename the new field to `detailed_stock`. This can be done in a single migration. If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Is it possible to use contains for django-jsonfield module? I tried, but it's not working.

Comment: `django-jsonfield` uses a `CharField` internally. If you use `__contains` to query that field, you have to be very precise in terms of spaces and quotes, eg. `__contains="'foo':3"` would not match against `{"foo": 3}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django and have used:

```py
from json_field import JSONField
```

Then you can not benefit the SQL lookup. As mentioned above, JSONField overrides the
TextField only. It validates the JSONformat and dumps as string.

```py
class JSONField(models.TextField):
    """ Stores and loads valid JSON objects. """
```

Instead use

```py
from django.db import models
data = models.JSONField(null=True)
```