# Get all entries with price greater than given price in json filed

Tags: django

I have a model `Van` with a `slug` field and a `price` field. I am using `MySQL`. I have to save different prices for all 12 months. I am using `JsonField`.

```
class Van(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    price = JSONField(null=True)
```

I am saving price like this and showing price of current month to visitor.

```
{'January': 987.0, 'February': 567.0, 'March': 567.0, 'April': 456.0, 'May': 6.0, 'June': 654.0, 'July': 456.0, 'August': 456.0, 'September': 456.0, 'October': 546.0, 'November': 89.0, 'December': 456.0}
```

**Problem**
I have to add an filter for min and max price. I don't know how can I do this. I have tried this `Van.objects.exclude(price__June__gte=340)` but this is raising error

```
Unsupported lookup 'June' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I searched the error and found this only work in `postgres`.

I know this solution `query = User.objects.filter(data__campaigns__contains=[{'key': 'value'}])` but i don't need exact matching.Is there any other method to filter vans by price?

Comment: do you check this? query = User.objects.filter(data__campaigns__contains=[{'key__gte': 'value'}])

Comment: Do you have to use a `JsonField`? The query would be much simpler and faster by adding 12 price fields to the model, one for each month.

Comment: @Saeed, I am using django-jsonfield which is a textfield. Django converts it into json by loads function. Thats why lookups will not work. Check this answer to understand clearly https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986802/10084728. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Ralf, Actually I don't know actual categories for price. 2 weeks ago, clients wanted price for 3 seasons, now for all 12 months. It may change again. That's why I am using JSON field.